# eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse - maven command usage

Tags: eclipse, web-services, maven, m2e, wsimport

I have a maven project wherein i am consuming a webservice using `wsimport` as a goal during project build.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- -->
            <configuration>
                <wsdlUrls>
                    <wsdlUrl>http://localhost:8081/email-service/services/EmailService?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
                <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated</sourceDestDir>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
<finalName>EmailServiceClient</finalName>
```

I build the project using `clean install` command. The artifacts/classes are generated in `target->generated` directory. So far so good.

Now when i tried to access any of the generated class in my `src` directory, i get compiler error stating that the class is not defined. My peer told me to build the project using

```
eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

I did and it solved the problem. I was able to use those generated classes very easily. Now I am wondering

- what is actually happening with this command?
- What is the use?
- Am i actually following the correct way to consume? I know i can also use `wsdl2java` but what is wrong with this?

Has anyone ever encountered this type of situation? Please throw some light on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure the reason behind your problem " when i tried to access any of the generated class in my src directory, i get compiler error stating that the class is not defined. "
But I can tell you the meaning of command you are using

As far as I know in maven we can define more than one goal at a time to execute so

```
eclipse:clean   \\Deletes the .project, .classpath, .wtpmodules files and .settings  folder used by Eclipse.

eclipse:eclipse \\build the project into eclipse project like structure.
```